# How to handle failure cases and scanner timeout callback in zebra using DataWedge in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, barcode-scanner, datawedge

Used DataWedge feature to scan the barcode in zebra device and send it back to device using intent.

I used below code to receive scanned data using intent.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        //  DataWedge intents received here
        if (intent.hasExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)) {
            Log.v(tag, "onNewIntent()")
            //  Handle scan intent received from DataWedge
            val barcodeData = intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)
            Log.v(tag, "scanData: $barcodeData")
        }
    }
```

I need to know how to handle scanner failure cases & scanner timeout callback?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API to let you know the scan has timed out.  The best way to achieve this would probably be to use the [Register_For_Notification API](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-0/guide/api/registerfornotification/) and detect when the scanner goes from SCANNING to WAITING, if that transition is not accompanied by a successful scan you can assume the scan timed out or the user released the trigger.  I have a [sample app](https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-Quick-Suspend-Scanner) showing how to register for the scanner state.

Comment: After scanner started scanning then I need to hide progress bar when scanner gets timeout without reading data. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I can't think of any, if I were implementing that I would use the Register_For_Notification API